# как правильно добавить Select в grid?

Tags: php, magento

У меня есть атрибут в таблице `eav_attribute` который я сам добавил:

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'aprove', array(
    'group'     => 'Special Attributes',
    'input'         => 'boolean',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'label'         => 'AproveProduct',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'default' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'searchable' => 1,
    'filterable' => 0,
    'comparable' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'  => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

Нужно реализовать возможность чтоб в `grid`  отображался `select` и зависимо от того 0 или 1 в таблице установлено отображало yes/no з возможностью выбрать,

Делаю это так:

```
$this->addColumn('dropdown', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Aprove public'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index' => 'aprove',
            'type' => 'select',
            'values' => array(1 =>'yes',  0 =>'no')
        ));
```

Но лишь выбрасывает ошибку!

**Как это сделать правильно ?**

Comment: так вроде селект нужен, у меня сейчас нет под рукой кода реализации но я делал через один обсервер который модифицирует грид второй отслеживает massaction этого грида и сохраняет. проще добавить massaction выбираешь продукты, в massaction выбираешь aprove и сохраняешь в общем.

Comment: @Naumov, если вдруг появиться этот код под рукой - буду благодарный за пример )

Comment: капайте к масэктион это будет проще всего

Comment: код непоявиться точно

Comment: @Naumov, я уже это сделал )

Comment: @Naumov, дайте еще подсказку, если не сложно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545512/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-grid