# Как создать несколько массовых действий grid?

Tags: magento, grid

Мне нужно реализовать **несколько** массовых действий в grid . 
Одно действие удаления реализую так:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('entity_id');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Delete'),
            'url' => $this->getUrl( '*/*/massDelete'),
        ));
  return $this;
    }
```

В контролере обрабатываю массив и все работает корректно.

Но как сделать несколько массовых действий ?

Например если сделать так:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('entity_id');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Delete'),
            'url' => $this->getUrl( '*/*/massDelete'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('submit', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Aprove'),
            'url' => $this->getUrl( '*/*/massAprove'),
        ));


        return $this;
    }
```

То получается бред. Всегда будет обрабатываться Delete.

**Каким способом можно реализовать такую возможность ?**

**Код massAproveAction**

```
public function massAproveAction()
    {
        $products  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id', null);
        if (is_array($products) && sizeof($products) > 0){
            try{
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setId($product)->setAprove(1);
                }
            }catch (Exception $e){
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getTraceAsString());
            }
        }else{
            $this->_getSession()->addError('Please select product');
        }
    }
```

Comment: так это должно работать, при выборе `Aprove` к стати правильнее `approve` будет выполняться `massAprove`

Comment: @Naumov, тоже надеялся, что будет работать. Но при выборе aprove - все удаляется !

Comment: код action скопипасть плиз в вопрос. И id элемента исправь на approve а не submit

Comment: @Naumov, добавил код

Comment: А где load() или collection product? и метод save куда то делся. Какая версия magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй так

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
$product = $productCollection
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('aprove')) // тут могу ошибаться может быыть метод addFieldToSelect
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array(
       'in' => $products
    ));
    ->load();
//  в верху сформировали коллекцию продуктов
foreach($product as $_product) {
  $_product
      ->setAprove(1) // ставим approve
      ->save(); // и сохраняем
}
```

Для проверки поставьте `die('approveAction')` и `die('deleteAction')` или точки остановки в `xdebug`, для исключения того что срабатывает не правильно rout massaction.

Далее необходимо заменить id поляс `submit` на `aprove` что бы исключить повторения id, так как форма massaction сабмититься js могут быть ошибки и сдесь.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: В `action` была проблема, или `id` @Maybe_V ?

Comment: была проблема в  id, невнимательность + мало практики! 
 

Последний вопрос если можно: `addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array(
       'in' => $products
    ));` там должно быть `in` или `id` ?

Comment: @Maybe_V это тип запроса http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724192/magento-collection-filter т.е. `in => array(1,2,3,4)` на mysql будет `IN(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 0):

Блоки можно не удалять, а делать их не доступными через `display: none;`.

Обрабатывать их появление и скрытие можно через медиа запросы `@media (max-width: 900;)`